# Virtualbox start up failed after the macOS upgraded to Big Sur

Tags: macos, virtualbox

As mentioned in the title, the question is:

```
Is there any way I'm able to use the Virtualbox in the macOS Big Sur?
```

Here are some details:

macOS: Big Sur 11.0 Beta (20A5343i)

Virtualbox version: 6.1.12 r139181 (Qt5.6.3)

After upgrade, when I launch the machine, it pop out the dialog saying:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Make sure the kernel module has been loaded successfully.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

What I have done:

1. Update the xcode to 12 beta, and the latest commandline tool (Just blindly updated)
2. Update the vagrant to the 2.2.9 (Not relevant, I think)
3. Found a lot of related threads by google, which happened since 2014, none worked in my case.
4. Reinstalled everything.
5. [VBoxManage hostonly create] gave me error.

(To the moderators, this is not a general software problem, as the Virtualbox is widely use by the vagrant which is quite popular in the local dev setting)

Comment: Got the bad news from virtualbox issue tracker https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19795 ...Currently the Big Sur beta is not supported by Virtualbox

Comment: It's not just `not supported`, the developers of VirtualBox just told everyone they don't care... and that developer beta is for someone else, not developers...

Comment: @zhangv This is supported now.

Comment: Plenty of people are still unable to run or install VirtualBox on Big Sur. See the issue in the original comment.